# AWS Cross-account pass role is not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to create an AWS CodePipeline that deploys code stored in a CodeCommit repository stored in Account B = HUB Account into Account A = production Account. CodePipeline is available on Account A.

What has been done:

KMS key - Account A:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:root"
        },
        "Action": "kms:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow access for Key Administrators",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/Admin",
                
            ]
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Create*",
            "kms:Describe*",
            "kms:Enable*",
            "kms:List*",
            "kms:Put*",
            "kms:Update*",
            "kms:Revoke*",
            "kms:Disable*",
            "kms:Get*",
            "kms:Delete*",
            "kms:TagResource",
            "kms:UntagResource",
            "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
            "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/service-role/code-build-glue-accountA-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/service-role/codepipeline-accountA-service-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/cloud-formation-role-accountA-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/service-role/code-build-glue-accountA-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/cloud-formation-accountB-role"
            ]
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/service-role/code-build-glue-accountA-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/service-role/codepipeline-accountA-service-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/cloud-formation-role-accountA-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/service-role/code-build-glue-accountA-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/cloud-formation-accountB-role"
            ]
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:ListGrants",
            "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

S3 Bucket policy - Account A

```
 {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/codepipeline-service-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/cloud-formation-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/cross-account-role"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline",
            "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline*"
        ]
    }
]}
```

CodePipeline ServiceRole - policy to assume Account B in Account A:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/cross-account-role"
        ]
    }
}
```

Cross Account Role - trusted relationship - Account B

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Cross Account policy - Account B

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:*",
                "codedeploy:*",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "codebuild:*",
                "s3:*",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Pipeline.json file - Account A:

Info: the pipeline has for build and deploy stages two actions: build lambda, build glue and corresponding deploy lambda, deploy glue.

```
{
    "pipeline": {
        "name": "cross-account-deployment-code-pipeline",
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/service-role/codepipeline-service-role",
        "artifactStore": {
            "type": "S3",
            "location": "codepipeline-eu-west-2",
            "encryptionKey": {
                "id": "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:ACCOUNT_A:key/keyid",
                "type": "KMS"
            }
        },
        "stages": [
            {
                "name": "Source",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeCommit",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/CrossAccountRole",
                        "configuration": {
                            "BranchName": "main",
                            "OutputArtifactFormat": "CODE_ZIP",
                            "PollForSourceChanges": "false",
                            "RepositoryName": "repository-AccountB"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": [],
                        "region": "eu-west-2",
                        "namespace": "SourceVariables"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Archive",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Archive",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "S3",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "BucketName": "assets-codecommit",
                            "Extract": "true"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "region": "eu-west-2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Build",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Build-Glue-Jobs",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Build",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeBuild",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "ProjectName": "code-build-glue-project"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "region": "eu-west-2",
                        "namespace": "BuildVariables"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Build-Lambda",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Build",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeBuild",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "ProjectName": "code-build-lambda-project"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildLambdaArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "region": "eu-west-2",
                        "namespace": "BuildLambdaVariables"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Deploy",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Deploy-Glue-Jobs",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CloudFormation",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "ActionMode": "REPLACE_ON_FAILURE",
                            "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND",
                            "OutputFileName": "create-glue-stack-output.json",
                            "ParameterOverrides": "{\"Environments\":\"PROD\"}",
                            "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/cloudformation-accountB-role",
                            "StackName": "glue-stack",
                            "TemplatePath": "BuildArtifact::output-glue-deploy.yaml"
                        },
                        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/CrossAccountRole",
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "region": "eu-west-2",
                        "namespace": "DeployVariables"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Deploy-Lambda-Functions",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CloudFormation",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "ActionMode": "REPLACE_ON_FAILURE",
                            "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND",
                            "OutputFileName": "create-lambda-stack-output.json",
                            "ParameterOverrides": "{\"Environments\":\"PROD\"}",
                            "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/cloudformation-accountB-role",
                            "StackName": "lambda-stack",
                            "TemplatePath": "BuildLambdaArtifact::output-lambda-deploy.yaml"
                        },
                        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/CrossAccountRole",
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildLambdaArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "region": "eu-west-2",
                        "namespace": "DeployLambdaVariables"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "version": 62
    }
}
```

When I release the changes in the pipeline - I get error below:
[image]

Due to the fact that Cross-account pass role is not allowed.
What I am doing wrong?
I have checked multiple resources and I can not find what I am missing.